# pushing ViewController in two navigationcontroller

Tags: swift3

[image]

In Above Image In place of back button I want to push that side menu only but no need here back `NavigationController` and I am using swReveal `viewController` to pass sidemenu but here working side menu but no need that back button navigation controller

Comment: Did you follow all steps of SWReveal library ?

Comment: can you share your storyboard screen short

Comment: @IBAction func DashBoardAction(_ sender: Any) {
    

    let Storyvc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabBarvc = Storyvc.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"tabbarvc" ) as! UITabBarController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBarvc, animated: true)
 

    print("sucess")

  }

Comment: just hide the UINavigationbar in tabbar vc issue solved